# Remove string from filename not working as expected

Tags: regex, rename

I'm trying to remove some substring from a group of files. The files have the following names

```
0_00008.obj
0_00009.obj
0_00010.obj
0_00011.obj
```

and I want them to be

```
8.obj
9.obj
10.obj
11.obj
```

I have tried to use `rename` like this

```
rename '/s/0_0+//;' *.obj
```

but nothing is happening?
I have checked the regex string and looks it can match correctly what I want to remove so, am I using rename incorrectly?

Comment: Does `0_00000.obj` exist?

Comment: No, the first one is 0_00001.obj

Comment: Oh okay, then the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57860056/2191572) provided by Code Maniac should work.

Comment: What is wrong with the pattern I'm using?

Comment: I don't know about the specifics of `rename`'s regex engine but using a Regex visualizer such as https://regex101.com/ will help you out A LOT. For starters you seem to be trying to match forward slashes but your sample data has no forward slashes. Same thing goes for that trailing semi-colon.

Comment: Where does the `rename` command come from? Is this a programming language or Windows Powershell or something else?

Comment: `rename` perl script in archlinux

Comment: sorry. I thought I was using rename perl script, but in fact, it was a less powerful binary version. `perl-rename` did the job

Comment: Well that seems like an important detail. By the way, that detail is exactly what "regex flavor" refers to. All regex implementations have subtle nuances which make them incompatible between programming languages and commands so specifying the regex flavor is always important. Just look at regex101 and you will see a list of "flavors" on the left side and you can click "Code Generator" to see even more.

Comment: thanks. now I know. It's the first time I use regex for something useful :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pattern

```
^[0_]*
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/aT4AZ7/1/)

Comment: It doesn't work neither. I have tried `rename 's/^[0_]*//;' 0_000002.obj`

Comment: @jjcasmar which regex flavor you're working with ? also why `s` flag ? you need to use `m` flag if your input is spanning across lines

Comment: I dont understand what means refex flavor. I'm using `rename` perl script in archlinux. The `s/...` is because I found like that in some examples (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33279/how-can-i-rename-multiple-files-by-removing-a-character-or-string)